# Ist der Ausdruck "unter dem Strich" umgangssprachlich?

Tags: phrase

> Unter dem Strich zeigt sich wieder einmal....

Eignet sich der Ausdruck "unter dem Strich" für schriftliche Texte wie z.B. Stellungnahmen , Aufsätze und so oder wird er als stilischer Fehler wahrgenommen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Seite [Linguee](http://www.linguee.de) eignet sich hervorragend, Phrasen zu finden, und fremdsprachige Übersetzungen dazu zu finden. Vor allem wird zu den Phrasen auch ein kurzer Kontext mitgeliefert.

Der Korpus, aus dem dort die mehrsprachigen Textbeispiele genommen werden, enthält sehr viele Texte, die die europäische Union produziert (denn die EU muss so gut wie alles, was sie an Texten produziert, in allen Sprachen aller EU-Länder herausgeben).

Das bedeutet aber auch, dass dieser Korpus vorwiegend sprachlich hochwertige Texte enthält, also Texte, die oftmals stilistisch hochwertiger sind als so manche Zeitungsartikel.

Wenn man also eine Phrase in diesem Korpus mehrfach wiederfindet, kann man davon ausgehen, dass sie nicht (ausschließlich) umgangssprachlich ist.

In diesem Korpus findet man sehr viele Beispiele für [unterm Strich](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/unterm+strich.html) und auch für [unter dem Strich](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/unter+dem+strich.html).

Die Phrase findet man also in beiden genannten Varianten in offiziellen Dokumenten des EU-Parlaments. Daraus schließe ich: Diese Phrase wird nicht nur umgangssprachlich verwendet. Man darf sie also durchaus auch in Geschäftsbriefen, Zeitungsartikeln, Büchern und ähnlichen Textsorten verwenden.

Answer (score 7):

Ich fürchte, es ist eine Frage des Sprachgefühls und Einzelfalls, wann *»[unter dem Strich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Strich#Bedeutung1a)«* (nicht umgangssprachlich) ein akzeptabler Baustein ist, um ein Ergebnis zu beschreiben.

Wie  z. B. hier:

> - Die Verhandlungen haben **unter dem Strich** nicht allzu viel erbracht.
> - Wenn Sie einen Steuerberater beauftragen, bleibt **unter dem Strich** mehr für Sie übrig.
> - Im Vorjahreszeitraum sind **unter dem Strich** 2.500 Firmen mehr an den Start gegangen.
> - Das kann zu einem höheren Energieverbrauch führen, was sich **unter dem Strich** nachteilig auf die Umwelt auswirken würde.

Unmöglich klingende Negativbeispiele sind dagegen

> - **Unter dem Strich** bleibt es wolkig.
> - Die **unter dem Strich** beste Leistung zeigte Rudolf Kowalski.
> - **Unter dem Strich** bleibt es dir überlassen, was du tust.
> - **Unter dem Strich** sind Sie gesund.
> - **Unter dem Strich** entschied sich der Kegelklub für eine Reise ins Allgäu.

die wie folgt verbessert werden können:

> - **Im Ganzen** bleibt es wolkig.
> - Die **insgesamt** beste Leistung zeigte Herbert Kowalski.
> - **Letztlich** bleibt es dir überlassen, was du tust.
> - **Im Großen und Ganzen** sind Sie gesund.
> - **Im Endeffekt** entschied sich der Kegelklub für eine Reise ins Allgäu.

Bei deinem Beispiel würde ich *»unter dem Strich«* durch eine der genannten Alternativen ersetzen.

Comment: Ich selbst würde nicht _unter dem Strich_ benutzen, sondern immer _unterm Strich_. Die hier als 'unmöglich klingend' bezeichneten Verwendungen sind für mich lediglich umgangssprachlich-salopp und wenn man so will nachlässig formuliert, hören sich allerdings mit 'unter dem ..' seltsam an. Die Verbesserungen finde ich gut, hätte ich genauso gemacht, da erkennt man genauer das Gemeinte. Ich selbst würde nicht anderen Leuten vorschreiben wollen, wie sie zu reden haben, derartige 'unmögliche' Sätze kommen vor und das Gemeinte ist erschließbar, sonst hätte man sie ja nicht verbessern können.

Answer (score 4):

In einem schriftlichen Text, der eine persönliche Meinung wiedergibt, kann man "unter dem Strich" durchaus verwenden, etwa in einem Essay, einer Problemarbeit, Zeitungsartikel oder Leserbrief. In einem technischen oder wissenschaftlichen Text sollte man den Ausdruck besser nicht verwenden.